# Vue3 Axios - I can't send data to child component

Tags: axios, vuejs3

> Hello, I'm trying to send data to other component **(parent => child)** on **Vue3**. I'm using **provide()** function in parent's script >>>

```
provide(){
        
      return{

        itemsList : this.itemsList,
       
      } 
    },
```

> And I'm using **inject** function in child's script >>>

```
<template>


<small v-if="itemsList.length > 0"
      class=" text-red d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center mt-2">Length of the List: {{itemsList.length}}</small>


    
</template>


<script>
    
    export default{

        
        
        inject:["itemsList"]

    }


</script>
```

> this is my parent component's script

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3030/list").then(item_response => this.itemsList = item_response.data);
    },

    
    data() {
        return {
            
            
            itemsList: []
            
        };
    },

    provide(){
        
      return{

        myData : this.itemsList,
      
      }
        
    },
```

> this is my json-data >>>

[My Json Data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqRrL.png)

> but child component can't see data, how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this, as the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#inject) said:

```
Injections are resolved before the component's own state, so you can access injected properties in data()
```

```html
<template>

<small v-if="injectedItemsList.length > 0"
      class=" text-red d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center mt-2">Length of the List: {{injectedItemsList.length}}</small>

</template>


<script>
  export default {
    inject: ["itemsList"],
    data() {
      return {
        // initial data based on injected value
        injectedItemsList: this.itemsList
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice ! I did it but it still doesnt't work. I will show my Parent component. I edited my question. Could you check last code part ?

Comment: Can you show me your `http://localhost:3030/list` api json response?

Comment: I updated again

Comment: Did you import your child component to parent component? I don't see any import in your code.

Comment: yes I did it. I solved this problem but without **provide and inject** 
I used **props** and it works